# A closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{k^p}{k!(n-k)!}$

Tags: closed-form

Is there a closed form for
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\frac{k^p}{k!(n-k)!},\quad n=0,1,2\ldots,\,p=0,1,2\ldots.
$$
I tried to identify the sum with Stirling numbers...

Comment: I notice that the expression equals $$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} k^p,$$ which looks a lot like ${p \brace n}$, except it has $k^p$ instead of $(n-k)^p$.

Comment: @A.E Do I have to expand $(n-k)^p$? Thanks.

Comment: Take $k\to n-k$, profit.

Comment: @A.E What is $n\brace  p$. Maybe a binomial coefficient variant?

Comment: @TymaGaidash see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment and Pedro Tamaroff's suggestion, let $k \leftarrow n - k$.

Then we get 
$$\dfrac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{n-k} (n-k)^p = \dfrac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} (n-k)^p = (-1)^n{ p \brace n} $$

This result only holds if $p > 0$. If $p = 0$, 
$$\dfrac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k} = -\dfrac{1}{n!} $$